# Linear system with many solutions from a finite set

Tags: nt.number-theory, linear-algebra, integer-programming

Basically I am looking for a linear system with
many solutions from a finite set.

Choose a finite set of rationals $S$ and fix
positive integer $k$.

Let $A$ be a linear system with $n$ variables $x_i$ and
$n-k$ linearly independent equations.

> Is the number of solutions of $A$ with $x_i \in S$ bounded
>   by an absolute constant?

This might be related to integer programming or
some variant of SAT.

> If the number of solutions is bounded what is
>   lower bound in terms if $k$ and $|S|$?

Comment: I’m confused. Do you want lower or upper bounds? The lower bound is $0$, the system does not have to have any solutions in $S^n$. The upper bound is $|S|^k$, which is easily proven by induction on $k$, and it is attained by the system $x_1=\dots=x_{n-k}=a$ where $a$ is a fixed element of $S$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I am looking for constructions with many solutions. The system $x_1=\dots=x_{n-k}=a$ appears to have only one solution $(a \ldots a)$, not $|S|^k$ or am I missing something?

Comment: It has $|S|^k$ solutions, as you are free to choose any $x_{n-k+1},\dots,x_n\in S$.